# Files application won't open

Tags: nautilus

If I try to open Files nothing happens except a spinny icon and my computer fans running fast.

If I run `xdg-open .` then I get `Failed to register: Timeout was reached`

I've attempted to google but couldn't figure it out. No logs were written to dmesg or /var/log/syslog

Ubuntu 18.04

Edit:
Running `sudo xdg-open .` works but is not ideal as I'd be editing the files as root.

Comment: Run `nautilus` in the terminal. This will show eventual error messages in the console that may give a hint about the problem.

Comment: @vanadium thanks for the reply. Killing nautilus fixed the problem. I didn't even know that was what it was called! Thank you very much!